# How to test cloud functions Auth Trigger in firebase admin?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I created a service that should fire some methods when a new user is created.

```
export class CloudFunctionTriggersWrapper {
    constructor(
        private cloudFunctionTriggersService: CloudFunctionTriggersService
    ) {

    }

    private get logId() {
        return `[${this.constructor.name}]`;
    }

    listen(){
        functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
            console.log(this.logId, `new User created ${user.toJSON()} `)
            await this.cloudFunctionTriggersService.onCreateUser(user)
        });
    }
}
```

I run this code locally on NodeJs.

When I create a new user (from the mobile app Android client), nothing happens on the server side (the trigger is not getting triggered)

Do I have to deploy this to firebase for it to work ?

If so, what I if I change something in the method inside onCreate, do I have to deploy everytime I make a change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible.  The Cloud Functions SDK provided by Firebase only lets you build functions to be deployed to Cloud Functions to run on Google infrastructure.  It doesn't let you run your own triggers on your own hardware.

If you want code to run when a user account is created, you will have to write and deploy an [auth trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) to run in Google's cloud.

If you want to test your functions locally before deployment, you can use the [functions shell](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell) to manually simulate events that would be delivered to the function.